# Share your list of stock phrases / phrase templates

Tags: set-phrases

Do you keep a list of set phrases that you use often, or phrases that you'd use someday? I do. [Here's mine](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/7ad0a989-2ddd-4593-8408-06383d761f29/a30ae5b90c085089ae3e665cbdc31685), a list of phrases I've collected from work emails since three years ago.

Such a list, while seldom shared, can help us learn useful phrases from real world examples.

If you care to share, great! Please post your list as an answer, or a link to your list if it's more than a few. Also please add a word or two about its usage context. Something along the line of:

---

Example >

My list of conversation openers (childcare industry)

Most used:

- おはようさぎ... - Morning rabbit
- こんばんわに... - G'night alligator

---

Note to future readers: those lists should tend to be void of actual context. If you're unsure about its usage, it's a good idea to post a question about it!

Suggestions welcome if this question itself needs reframing.

Comment: It would be cool if you would add some furigana and/or english to the list.

Comment: Hey @ento: maybe a little more direction would help? Also: it would be a good idea to copy paste the content of your link into this post (perhaps adding some comments: might inspire more answers). I'm honestly not sure where we stand on these open-ended questions at the moment (meta is an endless mess on this). At any rate, I have turned it into a CW.

Comment: Very interesting and useful question. Thanks for sharing. @Nicolas too

Comment: btw what do you mean by "killer phrases"?

Comment: @HerrKaleun I'll take that into account when I re-organize it next time, which should be very soon. Thanks!

Comment: @Dave: Thanks for the input. - I hope to have avoided the subjective-open-endedness by asking for a real list that you actually use, which adds objectiveness to the answer. Reading up on [Guidelines for Great Subjective Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) leaves me feeling it's a-ok, especially since the question meets guideline "4. .. invites sharing experiences over opinions." Still, deciding which answer to vote can be subjective here.

Comment: @Pacerier: I originally meant it to be something along the line of "the spot-on, ultimate weapon you wield when you're in a certain situation", like "killer app", but not "killer bee". However, checking up on Google told me "killer phrase" is mostly used in the "killer bee" sense, so I've changed it to "stock phrases". Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @ento: well, I think it is definitely open-ended (as well as subjective, of course), since there is just no way to pick one answer out of all the answers... But I am personally find with it as a CW...

Comment: And BTW: I used to find おはようさぎ and こんばんわに really cute and funny... Until they started running these PSA as filer on TV 24/7 (shortly after the earthquake). *I* don't even own a TV, and I've still heard these a hundred times during that period... ;-)

Comment: This PSA: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsRm78ZSOgc

Answer (score 2):

Here is my list (please ignore the French translations lol).
Suggestions/corrections welcome!

それでは、水曜日の3時にお邪魔させて頂いても宜しいでしょうか？
OK, alors je viens chez vous mercredi a 3h ?

電話でお話していた件、
添付ファイルでお送り致します。
Comme convenu au telephone, je vous envoie le fichier

前回、必要であれば、あと一回伺うことになっておりましたが、いかがでしょうか？
もし必要があれば、ご都合の良い時間をご指定ください。
si necessaire, je peux venir chez vous encore une fois.
si necessaire, dites-moi le temps qui vous convient.

昨日、XX様からメールいただきAlfrescoの開発サポートに関する訪問は必要ないとのことでしたが、
必要であればActive Directoryの調査のために伺うことも可能です。
こちらについては必要があれば、ご都合の良い時間をご指定ください。
Hier, XX m'a dit que le support dev n'est pas necessaire mais,
si necessaire je peux faire du support Active Directory.
si necessaire, dites-moi le temps qui vous convient.

金曜日に御社にてコードレビューをさせていただけますでしょうか。
Je peux faire une revue de code dans vos locaux vendredi ?

よろしければ、ご都合の良い時間をご指定ください。
Si OK, dites-moi quel creneau horaire vous convient.

これで全ての成果物をお送り致しましたので、問題がないかご確認下さい。
Je vous envoie le fichier avec tous les deliverables, donc verifiez si c'est OK.

皆様（Bccで失礼します。）
Mesdames messieurs, desole pour le BCC

本日の17:00に御社にお伺いいたします。
je viendrai a 17h

最後まで完了せず、2.2.7までのアップグレードのみが完了となっております。
Sans aller jusqu'au bout, j'ai seulement upgradé à 2.2.7

問題を調査し、改めてご連絡いたします。
je vais investiguer le problème et vous recontacter

もし都合が悪い方がいらっしゃいましたら、ニコラまでご連絡ください。
si des personnes pensent que ca ne va pas, me contacter SVP

merci d'être venu chez nous
本日は弊社までお越しいただきありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

My favourite is "あ？そうですか？ごめんね！韓国人だと思ったんです！".  I'm pretty sure you'll find the occasion to use it (at your own risks) too :)